# C++ instanceof works for parent class but it doesn't for child class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning C++ developing a game with Unreal Engine.

I'm using the next code, copied from [C++ equivalent of instanceof](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-equivalent-of-instanceof), to check if an object is an instance of a class:

```
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T*) {
    return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
}
```

I have the following method signature:

```
void OnHit(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit);
```

Inside the above method I want to check if `OtherActor` is an instance of class `Paddle`. `Paddle` inherits from `APawn`, which inherits from `AActor`.

When `OtherActor` is a `APaddle` instance, the following code returns false:

```
if (instanceof<APaddle>(OtherActor))
```

To check if `instanceof` is work I have tried the following code, and it works (returns true):

```
if (instanceof<AActor>(OtherActor))
```

Why it does not work with a child class (`APaddle`)?

Comment: The result of `std::is_base_of` is correct. The **static** type that is being deduced for `T` is always `AActor`. Do a frame challenge for yourself. How would a mechanism relying solely on the static type system ever give you a correct result that depends on run-time polymorphism and the dynamic type of some arbitrary run-time object?

Comment: C++ is not Java. In C++ objects work in fundamentally different ways than they do in Java.  `OtherActor` is a pointer to `AActor`. Even if the caller passed in a pointer to a derived class, as far as that function is concerned, this is a pointer to the `AActor` class. `std::is_base_of` is calculated ***at compile time***. It produces a ***compile time constant***, and does not figure out the most-derived class of the object, at runtime.

Comment: `instanceof` does not check whether an object is an instance of a particular class, it only checks the relationship between types.  (If you look carefully, you will see that it never uses the value of its argument, only its type.) In other words, it's not equivalent to Java's `instanceof` at all.

Answer (score 4):

Your `isinstanceof` will only check the static case. Note that the result of your function does not actually depend on the argument `isinstanceof`, i.e. the object itself. It only depends on the *type* of the argument/object.

What you need is a dynamic checking. For that there is [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Something like this

```
template<typename Base, typename T>
inline bool instanceof(const T* t) {
    return dynamic_cast<const Base*>(t) != nullptr;
}
```

But note: for that to work you need virtual functions in `Base`. if `Base` is not a virtual base class there is no way in C++ to perform the instanceof check.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` will not work either, in every case. But only in specific cases. It is entirely possible that in this case it will fail.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Please show us your version of 'instanceof'.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas ìnstanceof` is not possible in C++ in the other case

Comment: There is no such thing, since as I mentioned before, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: It might help if your instance of compiles.  I think you are missing `const*`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  Yes, absolutely. I was too quick here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A minimal complete verifiable example is usually a good idea when asking a SO question.  Here is my attempt:

```
struct AActor {};
struct APawn:AActor {};
struct APaddle:APawn {};

APaddle paddle;
AActor* OtherActor = &paddle;

assert( instanceof<APaddle>(OtherActor) );
assert( instanceof<AActor>(OtherActor) );
```

the first assert is false, the second is true, and you want to know why?

`std::is_base_of` checks for type information, not instance information.

```
return std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value;
```

in the `APaddle` case, this is

```
return std::is_base_of<APaddle, AActor>::value;
```

which asks "is `APaddle` a base class of `AActor`?"  Quite clearly not.

In the `AActor` case:

```
return std::is_base_of<AActor, AActor>::value;
```

C++ considers `T` to be a base class of `T` -- you are your own base class (!) -- at least in this trait.  So it returns true.

The function *never examines the passed in pointer*, so the fact that your `AActor` pointer is actually a `APaddle` cannot matter.

If you want to dynamically test if a type matches, you (a) have to ensure that your types are polymorphic, and (b) should reconsider, and (c) use `dynamic_cast`.

```
struct AActor {
  virtual ~AActor() {}
};
struct APawn:AActor {};
struct APaddle:APawn {};

// is the argument pointing to an instance of the type X?
template<class X, class T>
bool instanceof(T const* ptr) {
  return nullptr != dynamic_cast<X const*>(ptr);
}
```

now your code works as expected.  Please note that `dynamic_cast` will not always work; there are cases where it is ambiguous, the type conversion is unreachable, or the types are not sufficiently polymorphic.  C++ does not mandate that all objects (be they structs or classes) support the built in run time type information (RTTI), and types that don't support it cannot be queried (by dynamic cast) about what their real type is.

For (b), querying the exact type of a polymorphic object violates the LSP and couples your inheritance hierarchy with your algorithm implementations in a way that doesn't scale well.

As an example caused by (b), suppose you have fruit, and fruit can initially be an apple or an orange.

You write your code with a bunch of dynamic casts to determine if the fruit you are processing is an apple or orange and handle it differently.

You then want to add in new class, mandarin.  Mandarin is supposed to act like an orange, but has a completely different implementation under the hood.

Every one of your dynamic casts detect your mandarin as a non-orange.

On the other hand, if you had a

```
virtual bool IsOrange() const = 0;
```

in your interface, and used that to detect Oranges instead of dynamic casts, then Manadarins could freely pretend to be Oranges without actually being one.

This requires that your interface actually be sufficient to solve your problems.

As an aside, that website you are using is written by someone who isn't competent at C++, consider using a different resource.